# how to know particular layer index in keras

Tags: keras

In my CNN model in keras i want to know the layer number or index of particular layers like say index of convolution layers. `model.summary()` will tell details of model and `model.layer` will tell layers of model. For example my model is following:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32,(2,2),input_shape=input_shape,activation='linear'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.1))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2,2),activation='linear'))
```

Then in above model Conv2D layer index is 0 and 5. This thing i want to know.

Answer (score 5):

The index of each layer is simply the index of that layer in `model.layers`. If you want it explicitly, you can use dict comprehensions to create the mappings:

```
{i: v for i, v in enumerate(model.layers)}
```

gives

```
{0: <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x7f182bcd1710>,
 1: <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization at 0x7f1840981828>,
 2: <keras.layers.advanced_activations.LeakyReLU at 0x7f184154b5c0>,
 3: <keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D at 0x7f184154be10>,
 4: <keras.layers.core.Dropout at 0x7f184154be80>,
 5: <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x7f18800593c8>}
```

Or the other way around:

```
{v: i for i, v in enumerate(model.layers)}
```

gives

```
{<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x7f182bcd1710>: 0,
 <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization at 0x7f1840981828>: 1,
 <keras.layers.advanced_activations.LeakyReLU at 0x7f184154b5c0>: 2,
 <keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D at 0x7f184154be10>: 3,
 <keras.layers.core.Dropout at 0x7f184154be80>: 4,
 <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x7f18800593c8>: 5}
```

It's perhaps more useful if you give your layers explicit names:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(2,2),input_shape=(32,32,3),activation='linear', name='one'))
model.add(BatchNormalization(name='second'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.1, name='third'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='four'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1, name='five'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2,2),activation='linear', name='six'))
dictionary = {v.name: i for i, v in enumerate(model.layers)}
```

gives

```
{'one': 0, 'second': 1, 'third': 2, 'four': 3, 'five': 4, 'six': 5}
```

Which you can use to lookup the index of layer by its name.

Comment: I think it's better to give same name to all Conv2D layers and then find what is index of Conv2d layer with help of dictionary